# CSS & HTML Effects on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make a scroll effect where the user scroll's down, and for three panels (will see in the code), the background will stay, and it will make an effect. I then want to make it so that after all three panels, it moves to another section, where the user will scroll down and it will move sideways. However, when I reach the end of the panelCause, the last bg-img stays and won't go away, meaning it blocks the next section. Is there anyway to stop this?

If you have any questions ask them...

Code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--CSS Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/prevention.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/generals.css">

     <!--GSAP Scrolltrigger Imports-->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

    <!--Website Icon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/Website-logo.png">

    <!--Title-->
    <title>Prevention</title>
    
</head>
<body>
        
    <!--Hamburger Menu Starts-->

    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
        <div class="hamburger">
            <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="statistics.html">Statistics - Numbers</a></li>
                <li><a href="where.html">Statistics - Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="prevention.html" style="border-bottom-width: 5px; border-bottom-style: solid;">Prevention</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-the-author.html">My Mission</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Slide Show starts-->
    <section class="home">
      <div>
        <h1>Prevention</h1>
        <p>Now that you know how much and where gun violence happens, its time to take action. We need to figure out how 
          to prevent it from happening. But before we are able to find out how to stop it, we need to find the main causes
          of it. There are a plethora of different causes, but below, I have divided them into three main categories. From 
          there, we will dive in to the prevention step, and find ways to prevent the violence from happening. </p>
       </div>   
    </section>
    
    
    <!--Causes Panel -->
    <section class="panelCause firstCause">
        <p>replace img</p>
    </section>
    <section class="panelCause secondCause">
        <p>replace img</p>
    </section>
    <section class="panelCause thirdCause">
        <p>replace img</p>
    </section>


    <!--Prevention Panel-->
    <section class="container">
      <div class="panel preventionContainer">

      </div>
      <div class="panel prev1">

      </div>
      <div class="panel prev2">

      </div>
      <div class="panel prev3">

      </div>
    </section>

    
    <script src="JS/prevention.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

/* Home */
.home {
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ),
    url(../images/first_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 50px;
    padding-top: 20em;
}

.home h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.home p {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}


/* Causes panels */
.panelCause {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 300vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
}

.firstCause {
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ),
    url(../images/age_bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.secondCause {
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),
    url(../images/race_bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.thirdCause {
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 1),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    ),
    url(../images/lff.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}


/* Prevention Starts */
.container {
    width: 400%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.panel {
    width: 100vw;
}

.preventionContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../images/cbp.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--CSS Files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/prevention.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/generals.css">

     <!--GSAP Scrolltrigger Imports-->
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>

    <!--Website Icon-->
    <link rel="icon" href="images/Website-logo.png">

    <!--Title-->
    <title>Prevention</title>
    
</head>
<body>
        
    <!--Hamburger Menu Starts-->

    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
        <div class="hamburger">
            <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="statistics.html">Statistics - Numbers</a></li>
                <li><a href="where.html">Statistics - Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="prevention.html" style="border-bottom-width: 5px; border-bottom-style: solid;">Prevention</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-the-author.html">My Mission</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Slide Show starts-->
    <section class="home">
      <div>
        <h1>Prevention</h1>
        <p>Now that you know how much and where gun violence happens, its time to take action. We need to figure out how 
          to prevent it from happening. But before we are able to find out how to stop it, we need to find the main causes
          of it. There are a plethora of different causes, but below, I have divided them into three main categories. From 
          there, we will dive in to the prevention step, and find ways to prevent the violence from happening. </p>
       </div>   
    </section>
    
    
    <!--Causes Panel -->
    <section class="panelCause firstCause">
        <p>replace img</p>
    </section>
    <section class="panelCause secondCause">
        <p>replace img</p>
    </section>
    <section class="panelCause thirdCause">
        <p>replace img</p>
    </section>


    <!--Prevention Panel-->
    <section class="container">
      <div class="panel preventionContainer">

      </div>
      <div class="panel prev1">

      </div>
      <div class="panel prev2">

      </div>
      <div class="panel prev3">

      </div>
    </section>

    
    <script src="JS/prevention.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```